# Как установить, точнее заставить работать, терминал сбора данных?

Tags: 1с

Кто подскажет, как установить, точнее заставить работать терминал сбора данных  `Cipher 8300с 1с 7.7`?

Понаходил документации, вроде бы установил, но не могу понять, как сделать выгрузку и т.п. Пишет, что тайм аут запроса истёк.

Comment: на комп выгружает? а в 1с нет? или вообще нет?

Comment: конфигурация-пример работает?

Comment: вообще не чего не работает. С начало при подключении в 1с писалось, что не может открыть COM3 порт, переименовал на COM4, после этого писалось что не может определить IR приставку, а потом вообще пишет , что ТАЙМ АУТ истёк. Не на ком ни на 1с не выгружает.http://www.scancode.ru/files/item/11/96/ пользовался этой инструкцией и их драйверами. Только вот, я не прошивал терминал.

Comment: Кто вообще работал с похожим терминалом?

Answer (score 1):

По моему, там скорость пониже надо поставить, по умолчанию ставится слишком большая, исправь в настройках.

Comment: в настройках COM порта или в 1С ?

Comment: в компе, и проверь вначале на проге которая с терминалом идет, потом на 1с переходи) алгоритм простой вначале проверяешь работу терминала, потом привязываешь к 1с

Comment: спасибо, попробую :)